# Coordinates of the Moon

Tags: fundamental-astronomy

How does one compute the right ascension and declination of the Moon at a given time (or for that matter, the altitude and azimuth)?

Comment: Do you want to know the equations or just a calculator?

Comment: Equations (fill)

Comment: I assume you don't want to use an online/email solution like http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons is that correct? How much accuracy do you seek? You can replicate HORIZONS calculations if you really want to. I assume you're looking at the geocentric ra/dec/alt/az? The actual position of the moon varies up to 1 degree depending where on Earth you are.

Comment: Does this question not help? http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-calculate-the-inclination-of-an-object-with-an-amateur-telescope

Comment: The computation of the position of the Moon is rather complex (depending on the desired accuracy) and requires a few pages of equations.  These can be found in e.g. this paper: http://esoads.eso.org/abs/1988A%26A...190..342C